# A property of the expected value of a Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

Let X(t) be a Poisson Process and $f\geq0$. Show that $E[e^{-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(W_n)}]=e^{-\lambda \int_0^\infty(1-e^{-f(t)})dt}$

($W_n$ is the time of the nth ocurrence in the Poisson Process)

Any suggestions on where to begin? This is an optional problem of my introductory Stochastic Processes class, so maybe is a bit too theoretical for me, but at least I would like to see how to solve it.

Comment: You can mimic the proof in Page 338 - Sidney I. Resnick's book: Adventure in stochastic process. Your Poisson process is just a special case of point process !

Comment: Might be a good start to think about the relation of $(X_t)$ and $(W_n)_n$. What do you know about the distribution of $W_n$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laplace functional for Poisson Process: $E[e^{-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(W_n)}]= e^{-\lambda\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-f(t)})dt}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673474/laplace-functional-for-poisson-process-ee-sum-n-1-inftyfw-n-e)